# Honda Unicorn missing during rain and cold weather

Tags: honda, motorcycle

I have a 2009 model Honda unicorn motorcycle. It's very difficult to ride during rain or cold weather, because of missing. I asked service center but they did not do anything. I have changed the CDI, ignition coil and air filter but the problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

Check the spark plugs and plug wires.  Maybe you've got a bad plug or a wire with a crack in the insulation that's letting in moisture.

Comment: To diagnose cracked wires, its best to check it late at night when you can see the tiny sparks earthing against the engine case/frame.  If the engine is dry use a small spray gun to lightly mist the wires, you should see faint arcs of electricity as they earth to the case/frame instead of arcing in the spark plug

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're on the right track.  Water/cold missing issues are usually ignition related.  I've been down this road a number of times myself.  It can be quite hard to pinpoint.  Look for cracked ignition components that might be letting water in/support condensation.

Another (but somewhat remote possibility) is water in the fuel.  Bad seal on the gas tank?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. That was because of water getting in carburetor .